# I want to backup my database to a shared drive 10.20.1.159, but the RMAN is not using my configuration parameters

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, database-backups, rman

**Please suggest how to fix the parameters so that I can write my files in the designated directory and the format I want.**

**Below is the RMAN SHOW ALL;**

```
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name ORCL are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION ON;
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '\10.20.1.159\CF_%F';
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK BACKUP TYPE TO COMPRESSED BACKUPSET PARALLELISM 1;
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE 'SBT_TAPE' BACKUP TYPE TO COMPRESSED BACKUPSET PARALLELISM 4;
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1;
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE 'SBT_TAPE' TO 1;
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1;
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE 'SBT_TAPE' TO 1;
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT   '\10.20.1.159\recovery\';
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE 'SBT_TAPE' PARMS  "SBT_LIBRARY=D:\ODB11GR2\opc\lib\oraopc.dll, SBT_PARMS=(OPC_PFILE=D:\ODB11GR2\opc\config\opc.ora)";
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED;
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF;
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128';
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'MEDIUM' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE;
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO BACKED UP 1 TIMES TO DISK;
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '\10.20.1.159\RMAN\SNAPSHOT\SNCFORCL.ORA';
```

**Here is the script I'm running:**

```
RUN
{
crosscheck archivelog all;
ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch01 TYPE DISK;
backup database plus archivelog;
crosscheck backup;
RELEASE CHANNEL ch01;
}
```

**Here is my startup file:**

```
set ORACLE_SID=orcl
set ORACLE_HOME=D:\ODB11GR2\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
echo "RMAN start at `date "+%F %H:M:%S"`" >E:\RMAN_Backup\logs\daily-rman-`date +%F`.log

D:\ODB11GR2\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\rman target=/ log=E:\RMAN_Backup\logs\daily-rman-%datetimeF%.log append cmdfile=E:\RMAN_Backup\scripts\daily_full_disk.rman

echo "RMAN finished at `date "+%F H:%M:%S"`" >> E:\RMAN_Backup\logs\daily-rman-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%.log
```

**Please suggest how to fix the parameters so that I can write my files in the designated directory and the format I want.**

Comment: What is DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST set to?

Comment: The DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST is set to a local drive E, but i dont want to change it so that my database won't be linked to a network where some issues can cause the database to stop. Is there anyway to backup using rman configuration parameters to a shareddrive without changing recovery dest?

Answer (score 0):

Step 01:
Test whether we can drive to external drive

```
rman target /
rman>backup database format '\10.20.1.159\recovery\Full_DB_%U';
```

If it fail then try:

```
rman>backup database format '\\10.20.1.159\recovery\Full_DB_%U';
```

If one of them work out then updating the following with "one backward slash" or "two backward slash" - pick up the one that workable!

```
backup database plus archivelog;
```

into:

```
backup database format '\10.20.1.159\recovery\Full_DB_%U';
backup archivelog all delete input format '\10.20.1.159\recovery\archive_%U';
```

Comment: The first one gave me cannot find path specified.
Second one gave me network name cannot be found.
How can i save my backup to a shared drive?

Comment: You should contact your Server Administrator performing mapping firstly! Then retry using mapping Drive location!

Comment: My network drive is already mapped

Comment: So you shoud use mapping Drive letter, e.g Z:\ instead of IP address

Comment: BTW, checking where Oracle software owner (installation user) have sufficient Privilege of read/write into that external drive too. Hint: open Windows services to get that user.

Comment: I already tried Y:\ didn't work

Comment: You have to open services to find out Oracle software owner, then make sure that Oracle software owner can read/write to Y:\ Drive.

Comment: The priviliges for drive Y are already given since we're signed in to the user with full access.

Comment: Please login as Oracle software owner, and copying any test file to Y:\. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with priviliges since the user im using has all access.
However, I tried and I'm able to copy to Y:

Comment: It seems unreasonable if you can copy file but can't create rman backup file in Y:\ while login uder Oracle Software Owner! No way!